# Don't refresh page after submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a site http://gamepoll.net and I want that when I click Create Poll, the page doesn't refresh. This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>League of Legends Straw Poll</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h1 class="text-center">Game Straw Poll</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form name="submitForm" id="submitForm" action="" method="post">
                            <div class="row">   
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="theme" name="game" onchange="ChangeBackground();">
                                        <option selected disabled>Select your Game...</option>
                                        <option value="League_of_Legends">League of Legends</option>
                                        <option value="Heartstone">Hearthstone</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Start typing your question...">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-options col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-option col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="option[]" id="option" class="form-control" placeholder="Options...">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="choice" name="choice" value="Yes">Allow multiple choice
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit|button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" onclick="SubmitForm();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Poll</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Poll created</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Share it: <a href="http://gamepoll.net/<?php echo $rand_value; ?>">http://gamepoll.net/<?php echo $rand_value; ?></a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/addfield.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/changebackground.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='norefresh.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code

```
function SubmitForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var game = $("#game").val();
var question = $("#question").val();
var option = $("#option").val();
$.post("submit.php", { game: game, question: question, option: option },
}
```

submit.php Code

```
<?php
//Include configuration file
include('includes/config.php');

//Define variables
$question=$_POST['question'];
$game=$_POST['game'];
$option=$_POST['option'];
$choice=$_POST['choice'];

//Generate random number
$rand_value=rand();

//Create temporary folder
mkdir($rand_value);

//Copy page of Ask Poll
copy('page.php', $rand_value . '/page.php');
rename($rand_value . '/page.php', $rand_value . '/index.php');

//Add data into database
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("Errore di connessione!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Impossibile selezionare database!");
$sql1="CREATE TABLE `" . $rand_value . "` (Question VARCHAR(200), Options VARCHAR(200), Choice INT(11))";
mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Impossibile eseguire la query!");

//Count number of Options available
$count=count($option);

    for ($i=0; $i<($count-1); $i++)
    {
        ${$sql . $i}="INSERT INTO `" . $rand_value . "` (Question, Options, Choice) VALUES ('$question', '$option[$i]', '$choice')";
        mysql_query(${$sql . $i});
    }   
?>
```

All works perfectly but the only problem is that when i click Create Poll button, the browser redirect me to submit.php blank page

UPDATE

This code doesn't work

```
function SubmitForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var game = $("#game").val();
var question = $("#question").val();
var option = $("#option").val();
$.post("submit.php", { game: game, question: question, option: option }
return false;
}
```

Can you write me an AJAX function as the last comment says?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form refresh the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837604/submit-form-refresh-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

place `return false;` at the end of your `SubmitForm` function and loose the comma at the end of the last sentence

```
function SubmitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var game = $("#game").val();
  var question = $("#question").val();
  var option = $("#option").val();
  $.post("submit.php", { game: game, question: question, option: option }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either place `return false;` at the end of the function SubmitForm or change `onclick="SubmitForm();"` to `onclick="SubmitForm(); return false;"`

Answer (score 2):

You can just add onsubmit="return false;" to your form:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
*****
****
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax function if you want that the page doesn't refresh on click the "Create Poll" button.
It loads the part of the page without refresh the whole page.